# Spring Cloud Stream kafka producer, producing to dynamic kafka topic

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I would like to create a kafka endpoint using spring cloud stream framework, which will have a http post api to `/{topic_name}`.How can I dynamically change `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.destination={topic_name}` property

I could use `confluent Kafka REST Proxy` implementation to achieve above functionality, but wondering if its possible to develop this in spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample that demonstrates these types of use cases where it uses dynamic destinations based on an http trigger. 
Take a look at the code and the README.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/source-samples/dynamic-destination-source-kafka

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamBridge with kafka-topicname and spring-cloud will bind it automatically in runtime. That approach also auto creates topic if that not exist, you can turn it off.

```
@Autowired
private final StreamBridge streamBridge;
  
public void sendDynamically(Message message, String topicName) {
    streamBridge.send(route, topicName);
}
```

It requires only: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers: ${KAFKA_HOST}:${KAFKA_PORT}`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_streambridge_and_dynamic_destinations